# How to configure the "Assign To" list in mantis

Tags: default, report, mantis

When a reporter creates a bug , in the "Assign To" drop down list , at present there is all the users i've created for my project.How to confgure the list so that only a single usere is listed in "Assign To"  list.

Comment: I'd also like to know how to filter the users by Project. Now I see users that belong to other projects.

Answer (score 2):

The config option **$g_handle_bug_threshold** determines which users can be assigned to issues. All users with access level >= this option will be listed in the "assign to" selection list.

Most likely if you see all users, you have either lowered this setting from its default of DEVELOPER to REPORTER (or even VIEWER), or all of your users are DEVELOPER or above.

Answer (score 1):

In the categories section , we can add diff entries regarding the application , i added sub modules , Each modules can be given an default assigne (a developers email) .So when ever the reporter , reports an issue , he/she needs to select an entry from the category list .This will make the bug assigned to the developer associated with that category.